# Magento 2.3.2: Active payment method on specific category for the products in cart

Tags: cart, payment-methods, category-products, magento2.3.2

I want to show payment methods for particular category products added in cart.

> e.g I have paypal and COD payment methods, so when X category Item in
>   cart then Paypal will show and other will hide, And when Y category
>   item in the cart then COD method will show and PayPal will hide.

So how can I achieve this?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this way using **payment_method_is_active** event observer.

Create `events.xml` file with the below content.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payment_method_is_active" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\MethodIsActive" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And create `MethodIsActive.php` with the following code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Payment;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
class MethodIsActive implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $productRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $this->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
        $categoryID = 155; //Add your category ID
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        $flag = false;
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $product = $this->getProduct($item->getProductId());
            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
            if(in_array($categoryID, $categoryIds)){
                $flag = true; 
                break;
            }
        }

        // you can replace "checkmo" with your required payment method code
        if($flag == false && $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="paypal"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
        }
        else if($flag == true && $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="checkmo"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
        }
    }
    public function getProduct($productId)
    {
        return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }
    public function getCart()
    {        
        return $this->_cart;
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }
}
```

Comment: Work like charm :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get it with `payment_method_is_active` event observer.

Create `events.xml` file with below content.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payroll_payment_method_is_active" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DisablePayment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And create `DisablePayment.php` with your condition.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_session;

    private $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
    Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager
    }

    /**
    * @param Observer $observer
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if($method_instance == 'your_payment_code')
        {
            if (in_array('category id to match', $this->getCategoryIds())) {
                $result = $observer->getResult();
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getCategoryIds()
    {
        /** 
        @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item 
        */
        $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $categoryIds = [];
        foreach ($items as $item){
            var_dump($item->getName());
            $productid = $item->getProductId();
            $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')- >load($productid);
            $categoryIds[] = $product->getCategoryIds();
        }     
        return $categoryIds;
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: how can I check by category products? can you please read my question again in details ?

Comment: Do you want this feature on the Checkout page?

Comment: Yes, on checkout payment section

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1 for your effort